# Type checking in commonJS modeles

Tags: javascript, node.js, typescript

Having such a simple JS app:

*add.ts:*

```
function add(r:number){
    return r + r;
}
exports.add = add;
```

*app.ts*:

```
var utils = require('./add.js');
console.log(utils.add(4));
```

I get no type checking error when passing in a string instead of a number:

```
...
console.log(utils.add("abc"));
```

There is no error info both in the IDE nor on the output of the `npx tsc` command.
I know that using the `ES6` syntax (`export...import`) type checking would work but my question is how to enable this checking in `commonJS` standard with `exports...require`?

I've created the app using standard `npm init -yes` and have installed `@types/node` and `typescript` itself (using Visual Studio Code as IDE).

Answer (score 0):

[Typescript Doc](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/modules.html#code-generation-for-modules) shows you how to use that when `module` is `CommonJS`.

So in your snippets, do following changes.

```js
// app.ts
import add = require('./add.js');
```

```js
// add.ts
function add(r:number){
    return r + r;
}
export = add;
```

Comment: Ok i know that i can achieve that with an `export` in `add.ts` but my question how can i do it using just standard `exports...require` as I've shown

Comment: Can You be so kind and answer to my comment?

Comment: I searched a lot but nothing, all I can do now is declare this type additionally: `var util: xxx type  = require('./add.js');` there seems to be no standard method.